# Game Architecture in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Let's say you're making a game.  In the game you have some state about the world: score, number of players, enemies, etc.  Let's say the game is sufficiently simple where it wouldn't be that bad to have globals in the file to update the world.  Not optimal, but that's one way to do it.  From an OO perspective you'd have a singleton object like a World object, with methods to query/update.

What would be best practice to detect key presses and pass the state of the presses into the engine?  Would it be something like:

```
  (let [presses {}] 
     (.addEventListener "keypress" #(!set presses (into presses {%1 true})))
     (requestAnimationFrame js/window (fn [] (do-game presses))
```

Comment: You may enjoy reading [“Purely Functional Retrogames”](http://prog21.dadgum.com/23.html).

Comment: Lots to think about.  I have it getting user input and was just debating with myself about passing world in like he talks about.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: Of course there’s no obligation to be *purely* functional in Clojure (as he is discussing), that’s why we have atoms, after all. But worth, at the very least, musing about. I think the key is striking just the right balance: less state is better, but too little is perhaps cumbersome.

Comment: I think core.async provides some interesting approaches to handling input like key presses and feeding it into a game engine. I found [this blog post](http://rigsomelight.com/2013/08/12/clojurescript-core-async-dots-game.html), in which the author makes a Dots game using core.async, really interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using core.async to capture and merge the events and translate them into game commands is a pretty cool way to go about this.

You can see an example in my snake game:
https://github.com/joakin/cnake/blob/master/src/cnake/ui.cljs#L140-L217

Once you have captured your input and transformed it into game events, you could pipe it to wherever you've got the game logic.

In my case, thats a go-loop that processes commands and contains the game state locally to that fn, and applies different functions to it and emits events for the UI to react to:
https://github.com/joakin/cnake/blob/master/src/cnake/ui.cljs#L140-L217

A more traditional approach would be to pass those commands to a function that would choose how to update an atom containing the game state.

There is a cool post about the core.async type of architecture on a game:
http://ragnard.github.io/2013/10/01/clojurecup-pong-async.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes that would work fine, Though there is no need for a singleton object for the global state, a simple `atom` will do fine. There are too many options for interactive Clojurescript programs such as this to recommend any particular one in this case.

Comment: Do you have any good resources to show the different options?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways to go about this, but I will show mine. I do this with baconjs and jquery wrappers for clojurescript.

```
(ns puzzle.input
  (:require [jayq.core :as j :refer [$]]
            [yolk.bacon :as b]))

(defn- read-key-input [e]
  (let [k (.-which e)]
    (condp = k
      38 :north
      40 :south
      37 :west
      39 :east
      :sit)))

(defn arrow-stream [$elem]
  (-> (.keydownE $elem)
      (b/filter (fn [e] (not= :sit (read-key-input e))))
      (b/do-action j/prevent)
      (b/map (fn [e] (read-key-input e)))))
```

I set up a stream of keyboard input on the body. I subscribe to that stream with something like this:

```
(-> (puzzle.input/arrow-stream (jayq.core/$ "body"))
    (yolk.bacon/on-value (fn [direction] (change-world direction))))
```

Now whenever the keypress is an arrow, the `change-world` function gets called with the direction.

https://github.com/Cicayda/yolk
https://github.com/Cicayda/yolk-jquery
https://github.com/ibdknox/jayq

Answer (score 0):

You could try Om for this as it works by creating the application state in an atom which is rendered in RequestAnimationFrame